# Full JWT appears in terminal but JWT in browser is incomplete

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, json, jwt

I do not know what to make of this. I am issued two separate cookies when I log in: one incomplete cookie for the browser (both Chrome and Edge) that does not include the User Info such as authorization codes. According to the console.log in the terminal and postman, I am issued full JWT tokens with the needed information. I am using a refresh token system along with the access tokens but I don't think that is the issue.

Incomplete JWT decoded:

```
{
  "email": email@google.ca",
  "iat": 1667537100,
  "exp": 1667623500
}
```

Complete JWT decoded (with roles*!)

```
{
  "UserInfo": {
    "email": "email@google.ca",
    "roles": [
      1,
      2,
      3,
    ]
  },
  "iat": 1667535054,
  "exp": 1667536854
}
```

---

auth.js

```
const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();
const authController = require('../controllers/authController');

router.post('/', authController.handleLogin);

module.exports = router;
```

authController.js

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
require('dotenv').config(); //remove

const User = require('../models/userModel');

const handleLogin = async (req, res) => {
  /* eslint-disable-next-line */
  const cookies = req.cookies;

  console.log(`cookie available at login: ${JSON.stringify(cookies)}`);

  const { email, pwd } = req.body;
  if (!email || !pwd)
    return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Email and password are required' });

  const foundUser = await User.findOne({ email: email }).exec();
  if (!foundUser) return res.sendStatus(401);

  //evaluate password
  const match = await bcrypt.compare(pwd, foundUser.password);
  if (match) {
    const roles = Object.values(foundUser.roles).filter(Boolean);
    //Create JWTs
    const accessToken = jwt.sign(
      {
        UserInfo: {
          email: foundUser.email,
          roles: roles,
        },
      },
      process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
      { expiresIn: '30m' } //change
    );
    const newRefreshToken = jwt.sign(
      { email: foundUser.email },
      process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET,
      { expiresIn: '1d' } //change
    );
    //prettier-ignore
    let newRefreshTokenArray = 
        !cookies?.jwt
            ? foundUser.refreshToken
            : foundUser.refreshToken.filter(rt => rt !== cookies.jwt)

    if (cookies?.jwt) {
      /* 
      1) user logs in but never uses RT and does not logout
      2) RT is stolen
      3)if 1 & 2, reuse detection is needed to clear all RTs when user logs in
      */

      const refreshToken = cookies.jwt;
      const foundToken = await User.findOne({ refreshToken }).exec();

      //detected refresh token reuse!
      if (!foundToken) {
        // console.log('attempted refresh token reuse at login!');
        //clear out ALL previous refresh tokens
        newRefreshTokenArray = [];
      }

      res.clearCookie('jwt', {
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: 'None',
        secure: true,
        maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
      });
    }

    //Saving Refresh token with current user into database that can be cross referenced to create another access token
    foundUser.refreshToken = [...newRefreshTokenArray, newRefreshToken];
    const result = await foundUser.save();
    // console.log(result);
    // console.log(roles);

    res.cookie('jwt', newRefreshToken, {
      httpOnly: true, // save to memory not local storage
      sameSite: 'None',
      secure: true,
      maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    }); 
    res.json({ roles, accessToken });
  } else {
    res.sendStatus(401);
  }
};

module.exports = { handleLogin };
```

refreshTokenController.js

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const User = require('../models/userModel');

const handleRefreshToken = async (req, res) => {
  //one refresh token per device that is rotated
  /* eslint-disable-next-line */
  const cookies = req.cookies;

  if (!cookies?.jwt) return res.sendStatus(401);
  const refreshToken = cookies.jwt;
  res.clearCookie('jwt', {
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: 'None',
    secure: true,
  });

  const foundUser = await User.findOne({ refreshToken }).exec();

  //Detected refresh token reuse - get a cookie but not a user linked to cookie
  if (!foundUser) {
    jwt.verify(
      refreshToken,
      process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET,
      async (err, decoded) => {
        if (err) return res.sendStatus(403);
        // console.log('attempted refresh token reuse!');
        const hackedUser = await User.findOne({
          email: decoded.email,
        }).exec();
        hackedUser.refreshToken = [];
        const result = await hackedUser.save();
        // console.log(result);
      }
    );
    return res.sendStatus(403);
  }

  const newRefreshTokenArray = foundUser.refreshToken.filter(
    (rt) => rt !== refreshToken
  );

  //evaluate jwt
  jwt.verify(
    refreshToken,
    process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET,
    async (err, decoded) => {
      if (err) {
        // console.log('expired refresh token');
        foundUser.refreshToken = [...newRefreshTokenArray];
        const result = await foundUser.save();
        // console.log(result);
      }
      if (err || foundUser.email !== decoded.email) return res.sendStatus(403);

      //Refersh token still valid
      const roles = Object.values(foundUser.roles).filter(Boolean);
      const accessToken = jwt.sign(
        {
          UserInfo: {
            email: decoded.email,
            roles: roles,
          },
        },
        process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
        { expiresIn: '30m' }
      );

      const newRefreshToken = jwt.sign(
        { email: foundUser.email },
        process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET,
        { expiresIn: '1d' }
      );
      foundUser.refreshToken = [...newRefreshTokenArray, newRefreshToken];
      /*eslint-disable-next-line*/
      const result = await foundUser.save();

      res.cookie('jwt', newRefreshToken, {
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: 'None',
        secure: true,
        maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
      });

      res.json({ roles, accessToken });
    }
  );
};

module.exports = { handleRefreshToken };
```

I tried looking over my code and I cannot find the solution.This is my first time posting on stackoverflow, so please let me know if you need any info. Thank you so much in advanced!!

Comment: i think. your problem is in. the "newRefreshToken" assignment.
const newRefreshToken = jwt.sign(
        { email: foundUser.email },
        process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET,
        { expiresIn: '1d' }
      );
Try to add the roless property here also. Hope this helps

Comment: You sir are correct! I don't know how I didn't see that or how that wasn't a problem before! You have my gratitude.